# Issues with JSONObject in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-json

I can't seem to fix this problem I'm having. In my MainActivity, I'm syncing my device's application database with my backend database in several Asynctasks, one for each table. Since I have a lot of different tables, I have a general setup on the AsyncTask and pass in a parameter that determines which table to sync like this:

```
protected void onResume() {
    if(isOnline()){
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ FORENINGAR });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ INFO });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ KALENDER });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ KAMPEN });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ KARTA });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ KONTAKT });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ MEDDELANDEN });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ OVRIGINFO });
        new loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB().execute(new Integer[]{ SANGBOK });
    }
}
```

The actual AsyncTask looks like this:

```
class loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        int activity = params[0];
        String url = urlList.get(activity);
        String json = null;

        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setReadTimeout(15000);
            json = readStream(con.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(json != null){
            JSONObject jObj = null;
            try {
                // THIS IS WHERE I'M STARTING GETTING A PROBLEM
                // LINE 536
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                // THIS IS WHERE THE RUNTIME ERROR OCCURS BECAUSE OF THE PROBLEM AT ROW 536
                // LINE 546 
                int success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray(getActivityTag(activity));

                    getContentResolver().delete(getContentUri(activity), null, null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        for(int k = 0; k < getColumns(activity).size(); k++){
                            String TAG = getTags(activity).get(k);
                            String VALUE = c.getString(TAG);
                            String COLUMN = getColumns(activity).get(k);

                            values.put(COLUMN, VALUE);
                        }

                        getContentResolver().insert(getContentUri(activity), values);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("No Success", getActivityTag(activity));
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{

        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

And the method readStream that's used in the AsyncTask:

```
private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String json = "";
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
                in.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

This is my LogCat:

```
06-25 18:43:18.089: W/System.err(3942): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at se.nollekollen.main.MainActivity$loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:536)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at se.nollekollen.main.MainActivity$loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-25 18:43:18.113: W/System.err(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-25 18:43:18.117: W/System.err(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-25 18:43:18.117: W/System.err(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-25 18:43:18.117: W/System.err(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-25 18:43:18.117: W/System.err(3942):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-25 18:43:18.121: W/dalvikvm(3942): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at se.nollekollen.main.MainActivity$loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:546)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at se.nollekollen.main.MainActivity$loadFromBackendAndPlaceInDB.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-25 18:43:18.125: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     ... 4 more
```

It appears as though the problem starts at line 536 which then causes the final runtimeerror at line 546.

The error only occurs sometimes, sometimes it's fine. It appears as though it occurs when I do quick entries out of and into the MainActivity - when I navigate throughout the app more slowly it's usually fine.

What's happening, why does this error occur and what's the solution? Thankful for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems w/multiple AsyncTask corrupting each other (although I do not see any obvious errors in your code).

My usual solution is to have operations like this inside an IntentService and communicate updates to Activity via broadcast intent.

This means I keep a BroadcastReceiver inside the Activity to catch the intent and update the UI.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

instead of triggering multiple AsyncTask why not just send single interger array with all values as parameter to one and inside AsyncTask just implement for loop to loop through integer array entries one by one.

Comment: As you initiate call from your activity's onResume method, when you navigate in/out of your mainactivity, it will lead to multiple calls initialization for the group of AsyncTask, leading to db locking or something which is leading to runtimeerror which is not handled. When you navigate throughout the app slowly you asynctasks have enough time of execution and update db. So i would suggest, when db updation starts put a progress dialog to disable any user interaction.